# How do I detect if certain SSID is available or not?

Tags: powershell, parsing

I have the following command that will list the available SSIDs. I'd like to have a small script that execute if a specific one of them is detected.

```
PS C:\Users\User> $Networks = (netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid | ?{$_ -like "SSID*"})
>>
SSID 1 : Home
SSID 2 : Guest
SSID 3 : i-Phone
```

Example:

```
$result = For($i = 0;$i -lt $Networks.count)
{
# parse through networks here? 
}

 $SSID = "i-Phone"
 if ( $Networks.contains($SSID))
 {
    return $TRUE
 }
 else
 {
      return $FALSE
 }
```

Comment: you could refine your filter to try and find the specific SSID, i.e.: `?{$_ -like "SSID*i-Phone"}`

Comment: Replace .contains with .match ... Match checks for the string. Contains checks for the entire object. Aka the whole line. Heres the documentation explaining the differences https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 1):

Using one of the suggested comments below and just splitting and trimming the string this has worked as needed:

```
$Network = (netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid | ?{$_ -like "SSID*$SSID"}).split(':')[1].trim()
```